# Start dialog from trigger

Tags: c#, triggers, dialog, queue, botframework

This is in C#, on a Skype channel:

Is it possible to start a dialog with a user from a trigger?

**Situation**:
On a timed moment I want to show a dialog to all registered users (from which I have a resumptioncookie) 
So I have an azure function to monitor the queue and trigger my bot. On that trigger I can send a simple message, but i want to start a dialog at that moment.

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController: ApiController {
  public async Task < HttpResponseMessage > Post([FromBody] Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null) {
     switch (activity.GetActivityType()) {
      case ActivityTypes.Message:
       //some stuff here, not important for now
       break;

      case ActivityTypes.Trigger:
       //This does not work:
       await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ExceptionHandlerDialog < object > (new BroodjesDialog(), true));

       //But this does:
       IEventActivity trigger = activity;
       var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Message > (((JObject) trigger.Value).GetValue("Message").ToString());

       await Resume((Activity) message.ResumptionCookie.GetMessage());

       var messageactivity = (Activity) message.ResumptionCookie.GetMessage();
       client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(messageactivity.ServiceUrl));
       var triggerReply = messageactivity.CreateReply();
       triggerReply.Text = $ "Let's do some talking";
       await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(triggerReply);
       break;
     }
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: C# or Node? which channel are you planning to use? This could be not possible on all channels. Please show us the code of that trigger where you are sending a simple message. Thanks.

Comment: Added relevant code on the original question.

Comment: Can you post the code for your Azure Function trigger?

Comment: Azure Function Code is the standard code that is generated when you create a bot on Azure. I only changed the Direct Line Api Key to trigger a different bot.

Answer (score 1):

Check this AlarmBot example provided with the bot framework, it shows how to start a dialog form an external event.

```
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AlarmBot.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method represents the logic necessary to respond to an external event.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ExternalEvent
    {
        public static async Task HandleAlarm(Alarm alarm, DateTime now, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // since this is an externally-triggered event, this is the composition root
            // find the dependency injection container
            var container = Global.FindContainer();

            await HandleAlarm(container, alarm, now, token);
        }

        public static async Task HandleAlarm(ILifetimeScope container, Alarm alarm, DateTime now, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // the ResumptionCookie has the "key" necessary to resume the conversation
            var message = alarm.Cookie.GetMessage();
            // we instantiate our dependencies based on an IMessageActivity implementation
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(container, message))
            {
                // find the bot data interface and load up the conversation dialog state
                var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
                await botData.LoadAsync(token);

                // resolve the dialog stack
                var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
                // make a dialog to push on the top of the stack
                var child = scope.Resolve<AlarmRingDialog>(TypedParameter.From(alarm.Title));
                // wrap it with an additional dialog that will restart the wait for
                // messages from the user once the child dialog has finished
                var interruption = child.Void(stack);

                try
                {
                    // put the interrupting dialog on the stack
                    stack.Call(interruption, null);
                    // start running the interrupting dialog
                    await stack.PollAsync(token);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // save out the conversation dialog state
                    await botData.FlushAsync(token);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ResumptionCookie` is deprecated since 3.5.5. (rip), Since now, you should use/keep track of `ConversationReference` if you plan to resume the conversation in the future.

To get the `ConversationReference` I'm using use Autofac directly in the controller.

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
{
    var convRef = scope.Resolve<ConversationReference>();

    StoreInSomewhere(convRef);
}
```

When you want to resume the conversation, you could use [`ResumeAsync`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/f570b9bebfaaa1eb5ac682e4107aa49c2a100e49/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac/Dialogs/Conversation.cs#L106-L116) or send a direct message to the user as shown below:

```
// this is the previously recorded CR
ConversationReference convRef = GetFromSomewhere();

ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(convRef.ServiceUrl));
IMessageActivity newMessage = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
newMessage.From = convRef.Bot;
newMessage.Conversation = convRef.Conversation;
newMessage.Recipient = convRef.User;
newMessage.Text = "This is the message";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)newMessage);
```